# JQuery dynamic table totals

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic, html-table

I have this table:

[image]

The table has data from every month, but only shows the selected date.

So, the question is: How can I do a total of Actual Hours and Extra Hours per month (visible data)?

This is how I build the table:

```
var total = 0 ;
    var actualTotal = 0 ;
    var totalEH = 0;

    var table=document.getElementById("fbody");
    for (var i=0;i<user.length;i++)
    {

        var row=table.insertRow(-1);
        var cellDate                =       row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell2                   =       row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell3                   =       row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell4                   =       row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell5                   =       row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell7                   =       row.insertCell(-1);
        var cell8                   =       row.insertCell(-1);

        var startAM                 =       user[i].reg_start_worktime_am;
        var finishAM                =       user[i].reg_finish_worktime_am;
        var startPM                 =       user[i].reg_start_worktime_pm;
        var finishPM                =       user[i].reg_finish_worktime_pm;


        cellDate.innerHTML          =       user[i].reg_date;
        cell2.innerHTML             =       user[i].reg_start_worktime_am;
        cell3.innerHTML             =       user[i].reg_finish_worktime_am;
        cell4.innerHTML             =       user[i].reg_start_worktime_pm;
        cell5.innerHTML             =       user[i].reg_finish_worktime_pm;
        cell7.innerHTML             =       calcTimeDifference(startAM.substring(0,2), startAM.substring(3,5), finishAM.substring(0,2), finishAM.substring(3,5), startPM.substring(0,2), startPM.substring(3,5), finishPM.substring(0,2), finishPM.substring(3,5));
        cell8.innerHTML             =       (calcTimeDifference(startAM.substring(0,2), startAM.substring(3,5), finishAM.substring(0,2), finishAM.substring(3,5), startPM.substring(0,2), startPM.substring(3,5), finishPM.substring(0,2), finishPM.substring(3,5))-user[i].worktime_fullhours).toFixed(2);

        if (cell8.innerHTML != "NaN")
        {

            totalEH                 +=      parseFloat((calcTimeDifference(startAM.substring(0,2), startAM.substring(3,5), finishAM.substring(0,2), finishAM.substring(3,5), startPM.substring(0,2), startPM.substring(3,5), finishPM.substring(0,2), finishPM.substring(3,5))-user[i].worktime_fullhours).toFixed(2));
            total                   =       (document.getElementById('box-table-a').rows.length-1)*user[0].worktime_fullhours;
            actualTotal             +=      parseFloat(calcTimeDifference(startAM.substring(0,2), startAM.substring(3,5), finishAM.substring(0,2), finishAM.substring(3,5), startPM.substring(0,2), startPM.substring(3,5), finishPM.substring(0,2), finishPM.substring(3,5)));
        }
    }
```

Thanks

**EDIT:**

Fixed:

```
var totalActuals = 0,
    totalExtras = 0;
var totalHours = 0;
var trs = $("#fbody tr").each(function(e) {
if($(this).css('display')!='none')
    if( $("td:eq(6)", this).text() != 'NaN' ) {
        // alert("Horro! "+$("td:eq(6)", this).text() );
        totalActuals += parseFloat( $("td:eq(5)", this).text() );
        totalExtras += parseFloat($("td:eq(6)", this).text());
        totalHours++;
    }
});
totalHours = totalHours*8;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, your table will have some rows that are visible, and some will be hidden. And, you want to calculate the totals for rows that are visible.

You can do this by looping through only the visible rows and accessing the columns required for calculating the totals.

```
var totalActuals = 0;
var totalExtras = 0;
$.each($('table tr:visible',function() {
    totalActuals += $(this).find(".actualHours").val();
    totalExtras += $(this).find(".totalExtras").val();
};)
```

But this will also return the header row. So I think you should assign a class to the rows of the table, and use the class in the jquery selector - `$('table .tableRow:visible')`

**Edit**

Here I had assumed that you have given the class "actualHours", "totalExtras" to the div's in which the actual hours and total extra hours are shown in each row of the table. If you haven't done so, you can use -

```
totalActuals += $(this).find("td").eq(5).text();
totalActuals += $(this).find("td").eq(6).text();
```

This will select the 5th and 6th columns of the row.

Comment: can you explain me what find(".actualHours").val(); does?
How can i make it find that specific column?

Comment: Thanks, i've changed it a bit. i'm just fixing some issues with the page i can post it when it's fully working